# On a very slow query, how do I indicate percentage of progress

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, query-notifications

I'm using ZEOS components to connect to an (ancient) MDB database.
I'm doing a query that reads in lots of data to bridge into a different database.

Is there a way to indicate progress as a percentage?

```
procedure TForm13.ActionReadInMemoryExecute(Sender: TObject);
var
  QueryLine: string;
  FullQuery: string;
  Tablename: string;
  i: integer;
begin
  i:= 0;
  TableMeter.DisableControls;
  try
    TableMeter.First;
    FullQuery:= '';
    while not TableMeter.eof do begin
      Tablename:= TableMeter.FieldByName('tabelnaam').AsString;
      QueryLine:= ReplaceStr(ImportQuerySjabloon, cTabelname, Tablename);
      FullQuery:= FullQuery + QueryLine;
      if (TableMeter.RecNo < (TableMeter.RecordCount -1)) then begin
        FullQuery:= FullQuery + ' UNION ALL ';
      end;
      TableMeter.Next;
    end; {while}
    QueryImportMeterreadings.Close;
    QueryImportMeterreadings.SQL.Text:= FullQuery;
    QueryImportMeterreadings.Open;  <<-- takes a long time
  finally
    TableMeter.EnableControls;
  end;
end;
```

Is there a way to indicate progress of the query, or can I only do this if I split up the individual queries and eliminate the `UNION`'s.
It takes about 1 minute to run, involving 8 unions.

I don't see any event that I can use for this purpose:

Or should I fake an OnCalcField on a field in the Query to do this (not sure if that will even work in principle).
<strike>Or attach a sequence? nope, gives unsupported operation on a Access DB</strike>

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment below, based on the answer by user1031312, you could put the data in a string grid instead, unless you depend on the functionality of the DBGrid. If a TStringGrid is OK, I can give you a good example if needed to divide the queries and combine the results in the same grid...

Comment: @JerryDodge, I only need readonly access, so a stringgrid would work for me.

Comment: Without knowing the total record count, it will be hard to display a 'x percent completed' information

Answer (score 3):

I say split up the individual queries and eliminate the union, make a timer around each query, depending on the avg time taken * number of queries remaining you should give an estimate / update a text field to say x out of y queries completed (time remaining: -time-)

Comment: Yea I guess I could create a Query component per query and run them one after the other. Problem is I'd like to show the data in a grid and that's kind of hard with the data all split up.

Comment: I don't think you need a query component for each, just after you're finished with one query, move to the next statement in the same component - but you do still have a clear point with attaching a data source to show the data...

Comment: If that is the case, then possibly creating your own client data set? You can combine results from multiple queries, or just add your own data on demand - But I've honestly never worked with them. By the sounds of your situation, if you decide to split each statement like mentioned in this answer, then you would need to combine the data somehow in your own data set, then attach that to the data source (thus working in a grid).

Comment: Sorry for so many comments, but you could also use a string grid to display your data - unless you depend on the DBGrid's functionality. If this sounds like an idea, I can give a good example :D

Answer (score 3):

I would split the huge query into individual queries; in code, you iterate over each query's result set and manually insert the values into a clientdataset (cds). The cds can be connected to a dbgrid. Then you can show when each query completes - you could also show progress after each tuple is handled, but you won't know how many tuples in total there are, unless you perform a separate query which returns a count of tuples. The problem with using such an unconnected cds is that you have to define the fields in code. Here is an example of something similar which I wrote last night - the queries all update one field in the cds.

```
const
 field1 = 'id';
 field2 = 'customer name';
 field3 = 'total debt';

procedure TTotalCustDebt.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
 strings: tstrings;

begin
 with qTotalDebt do   // this is the clientdataset
  begin
   fielddefs.add (field1, ftInteger, 0, false);
   fielddefs.add (field2, ftString, 32, false);
   fielddefs.add (field3, ftInteger, 0, false);
   createdataset;
   fieldbyname (field1).visible:= false;
   open;
   addindex ('idx0', field2, [], '', '', 0);
   addindex ('idx1', field2, [ixDescending], '', '', 0);
   addindex ('idx2', field3, [], '', '', 0);
   addindex ('idx3', field3, [ixDescending], '', '', 0);
   strings:= tstringlist.create;
   getindexnames (strings);
   strings.free;
  end;
end;

procedure TTotalCustDebt.PopulateCDS;
begin
 dsTotalDebt.dataset:= nil;
 with qTotalDebt do
  begin
   emptydataset;
   indexfieldnames:= field1;  // initially sort by customer.id
  end;

 with qDBills do
  begin
   params[0].asdate:= dt;
   open;
   while not eof do
    begin
     qTotalDebt.append;
     qTotalDebt.fieldbyname (field1).asinteger:= qDBillsID.asinteger;
     qTotalDebt.fieldbyname (field2).asstring:= qDBillsName.asstring;
     qTotalDebt.fieldbyname (field3).asinteger:= qDBillsTot.asinteger;
     qTotalDebt.post;
     next
    end;
   close
  end;

  // show progress indicator

  with qDReceipts do
   begin
    params[0].asdate:= dt;
    open;
    while not eof do
     begin
      if qTotalDebt.findkey ([qDReceiptsID.asinteger]) then
       begin  // customer already exists
        qTotalDebt.edit;
        qTotalDebt.fieldbyname (field3).asinteger:= - qDReceiptsTot.asinteger
                                  + qTotalDebt.fieldbyname (field3).asinteger;
      end
     else
      begin  // add new record
       qTotalDebt.append;
       qTotalDebt.fieldbyname (field1).asinteger:= qDReceiptsID.asinteger;
       qTotalDebt.fieldbyname (field2).asstring:= qDReceiptsName.asstring;
       qTotalDebt.fieldbyname (field3).asinteger:= - qDReceiptsTot.asinteger;
      end;
     qTotalDebt.post;
     next
    end;
   close
  end;

 // show progress indicator
 // more queries
 // at end, attach the clientdataset to the TDataSource
 dsTotalDebt.dataset:= qTotalDebt;
end;
```